# common use case scenarios for condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, c++11

A condition variable can be used to signal to other threads that something has happened:

```
mutex m;
condition_variable cv;

thread t1([&cv]{
    // processing
    ...
    cv.notify_one();
});
...
unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m);
cv.wait(lck);
```

But as you can see, there is a window of opportunity that the thread processing is finished and the notification is passing by before we get to wait to be notified, so we will wait forever.

In that case, a common solution is the use of a flag:

```
mutex m;
condition_variable cv;
bool done = false;

thread t1([&cv,&done]{
    // processing
    ...
    done = true; 
    cv.notify_one();
});
...
unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m);
cv.wait(lck, [&done]{return done;});
```

Is using a flag the common way to use a `condition_variable`, or is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: A `condition_variable` is not a *semaphore*, the use cases are/can be different, and the usage differs. You can simulate a *semaphore* with a mutex and a condition variable --which is what you did with the `done` flag: simulate a binary semaphore.

Comment: that makes sense, I was thinking of it as a semaphore indeed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A condition variable should always be associated with some *condition*, which you should test:

```
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(m);
    while (!something) 
      cv.wait(lck);
```

The condition is checked while the mutex is held, so that implies the mutex should protect the data associated with the condition, so you know it won't change between testing it and waiting.

The test is a `while` not just an `if` because some condition variable implementations (including pthreads-based ones) may wake up spuriously i.e. when noone signalled it, so you should check the condition in a loop and re-wait while it isn't true. There's an overload of `wait` that takes a predicate and automatically handles spurious wake ups by waiting until the predicate returns true, e.g. here's the above example modified to use a lambda that checks the condition:

```
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(m);
    cv.wait(lck, [&] { return something; });
```

(In simple cases I find the explicit `while` loop easier to read.)

A condition variable that is in use can be thought of as a 3-tuple consisting of the condition variable, a mutex and a predicate, which are conceptually bound together by being used together to wait on the condition variable.  All concurrent waits on a particular condition variable object must use the same mutex, and will generally also be waiting on the same predicate (or a related predicate that depends on the same data, protected by the same mutex.)

Comment: note that your example is equivalent to the predicate version of `wait`

Comment: Yes, but as I've edited it to show, it's not always easier to read the predicate overload

Answer (score 0):

Usually `condition_variable` variables are employed in scenarios where one thread detects that it cannot proceed and decides to wait until some *condition* (in the English sense) is met. The `condition_variable` itself is not the main mechanism to notify that the thread should proceed but rather that if any thread is waiting it should recheck as the state might have changed and it might be fine to proceed now.

One of the simplest examples is a producer/consumer queue, where the consumer will have code like:

```
void consume() {
   empty.wait( [&] { return !queue.empty(); } );
   // extract data from the queue and consume it here
}
```

That is, the thread is not just waiting on the `condition_variable` variable, but rather waiting until the state of the object is such that the thread can proceed. Similarly, notifying a `condition_variable` is not telling another thread to continue, just notifying any thread waiting for a *condition* to be met to retest because the state might have changed.

Going back to your use case, if the *condition* that needs to be met for your thread to continue is that the other thread is `done`, then using such a flag is perfectly fine.

Comment: is there any examples in which I'd use a condition_variable without a flag or condition of some sort?

Comment: @IonTodirel not that I can think of. In all use cases I hav encountered there was some underlying condition that determined the need to wait.

Comment: See my answer: using a condvar forms a 3-tuple of the condvar, a mutex and a condition; if you don't have "a flag or condition of some sort" then you're missing a third of the necessary ingredients to use a condvar (at least, to use it correctly and safely)

Comment: interesting, I was curious of why `wait`, on `condition_variable`, has an overload that does not take a predicate, it was probably for flexibility and relaxing the design

Comment: Libraries that implemented condition variables before C++11 usually had only that overload, but the fact is that code that uses those libraries (boost::thread being the closer) all end up looking the same: `while (condition) condition_variable.wait()`, which is the reason why they added the overload that takes a functor. Note that pre-lambdas, it was not that easy to write functors. With lambdas, the new overload makes sense, but for some simple cases it might not make sense, and a simple `while (!done) cond.wait();` might be simpler than writing a lambda.